# Why is this include not working in jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to conditionally include a css file in my jsp page based on some parameter:

```
<c:if test="${param.co == 'txmart'}">
    <link
        href="resources/css/txMart.css"
        rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
</c:if>
```

I cannot understand why this does not work... It always include txMart.css file...(even if `co` is null or having other value)
Do you see any issue?

Comment: Are you sure you declared the use of the JSTL core taglib in your JSP? What's the generated HTML code. Does it contain <c:if...?

Comment: Yeah, I've declared it: `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"` and unfortunately, the source code contains: `<c:if...`

Comment: Are you using the XML syntax to write your JSPs? I.E. Do you have a <jsp:root> element, or do you use the more classical JSP syntax: <%@ page ...>. Show us the code of your JSP (at least the beginning and relevant parts)

Comment: And if I put some conditional string in body it works...but in head, this one from here doesn't (`c:if` in head seems not to be interpreted)

Comment: @JB Nizet: I'm using <@ page ...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't declare the use of the core taglib correctly. When using the classical JSP syntax, the use of a taglib must be declared like this:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

The notation `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"` is used when the XML syntax is used. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13597_05/web.904/b10320/jspxml.htm for details.